# How to add multilanguage Posts in PHPBB forum

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I add Multilanguage support in PHPBB forum (English/Spanish). English is default language.
How I add Spanish posts. Only one editor is available for English.

I already add language successfully. All forum translate to Spanish language except Post that are still in English language. I don't know how to add Spanish Version for the post.

Answer (score 0):

PHPBB Language Packs are available and can be downloaded here

http://www.phpbb.com/languages/

Comment: I already add language successfully. All forum translate to Spanish language except Post that are still in English language. I don't know how to add Spanish Version for the post.

Comment: Spanish version for what post?

Comment: Forum posts would be user generated! Or you can translate every post to spanish before posting API http://translate.google.com

Comment: Yes but My Question is from where I add Spanish version because only one textarea is available for English Now If I add Spanish version (Text translate from google) In this editor it also show in English version as Spanish. I hope You can understand now.

Simple is that for others like wordpress if we Install Multilanguage support. When we add new post there is two textarea one for English and One for other Language.

Answer (score 0):

Posts that are submitted by a user are not translated by the software into any other language without a MOD.

Also, if you wish to have a second textarea to allow users to enter a spanish version of their post, that cannot be done withotu a MOD.

I am not currently aware of existing MODs to either of the above.